# How to redirect an assembly binding for a DLL irrelevant of the loading host

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a DLL that uses assembly binding via it's .config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This is needed because the dependencies load conflicting versions of Newtonsoft.Json (6.0 vs. 9.0) and the binding is needed to resolve the conflict.

the problem I have is that this DLL is a Powershell module, and is loaded by powershell. Its `.config` is ignored and the runtime throws exception:

```
My-cmdLet : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
ublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Normally I would resolve this by modifying the hosting exe `.config` file and adding the relevant dll section. But in this case the hosting .exe is Powershell, and I'd rather not mess with *that* `.config`.

Is there a way the DLL itself can resolve the binding properly?

Comment: You can subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and handle redirection there (either from powershell itself, or from your dll, though doing that from dll might be tricky).

Comment: Put it in the GAC, resistance is futile.  Or solve the problem the programmer's way: decompile the assembly with ildasm.exe, change the .assembly directive, put back together with ildasm.exe

Comment: @HansPassant GAC imposes deployment burden (is no longer an xcopy deploy), and assembly editing imposes build burden (I must push a modified nuget package for Microsoft.Rest...). I tried Evk solution and seems to be functional. Does it cause any unforeseen problems?